# How can I make a focus line invisible using CSS?

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I have a modal. When it pops up, I get an unwanted blue line showing the focus? How can I get rid of it while not changing the focus?

[image]

The code for the modal:

```
 <dialog id="popupDialog" style="display: none;">
   <div role="dialog" aria-labelledby="g-modal-title" tabindex="-1">
     <h1 class="g-heading-l" id="g-modal-title">{{t('sign-out-warning:heading')}}</h1>
     <div class="g-modal-content" role="document">
       p>{{t('sign-out-warning:paragraph')}}</p>
     </div>
     <button class="g-button" id="closePopup">
       {{ t('sign-out-warning:continue') }}
     </button>
   </div>
</dialog>
```

And the script:

```
document.getElementById("popupDialog").showModal();
```

If push comes to shove, I'll settle for the shape and size of the blue line matching that of the popup box.

Comment: Use: `outline: none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This border is used to show that the element is focused (i.e. you can type in the input or press the button with entering). You can remove it with outline property, though:

```
popupDialog:focus {
   outline: none;
}
```